# OpenOffice Python macros: Where can I find useful documentation?

Tags: python, macros, openoffice-calc

I'm trying to make a macro for OpenOffice Calc that will toggle the background color of cells containing a user-specified value. Since I don't know OpenOffice Basic and have no desire to learn it, I'd like to write my macro in Python.

The trouble is, I can't find any useful documentation on how to write Python macros. From the reading I've done, it appears that I can't set up a dynamic environment  from where I can examine the appropriate object(s) themselves, so I'll have to rely solely on documentation. Where can I learn how to write my macro?

EDIT:

I already know about "[Python as a Macro Language](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Python_as_a_macro_language)," but it only answers where to put Python files. It says nothing about the API, how to search for and modify cells, etc.

In addition, there's no information about `XSCRIPTCONTEXT`, which OOo apparently provides as a global variable. Since I can't run interactively, I can't really interrogate that variable to learn about it.

EDIT 2:

I've found a number of pages that give bits and pieces of info, but they're either terribly incomplete or they assume a comprehensive pre-existing knowledge of the UNO API. So far, I haven't found anything useful. I simply don't have the time to try to learn the entire API just so I can understand one portion of it--especially since I'd have to learn C++ just so I could understand the syntax used in the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

I went through the same motions and so wrote a blog post to share with others what I have learned. Pity that now (almost six years later) the documentation and examples are still so scarce.

For learning the api, check out the two helper functions in `dev.py`

https://onesheep.org/scripting-libreoffice-python/

About your specific need to explore XSCRIPTCONTEXT - it is not available when running through the socket, but you can explore the interface here:

http://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/script/provider/XScriptContext.html